# Error on Wampserver - Depreciated : mysql_connect(): the mysql extension is depreciated

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am getting this error on my Wampserver

```
Depreciated : mysql_connect(): the mysql extension is depreciated and will be removed in future use mysqli or pdo
```

That was the error am getting when I tried to select my database on wamp server with php 5.5.12 sql 5.6.17

Comment: What's your question? The message is quite clear. You shouldn't be using `mysql*` functions! and shouldn't use any reference materials that teach them, as it's almost guaranteed to teach you to create injection vulnerabilities for yourself.

Comment: It's so awesome. For months everywhere you read *mysql*, there is a warning that you shouldn't use this lib anymore. A developer needs to be up to date with technics, the internets move on way too fast to rely on legacy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite all of your database connections and queries.

You're using `mysql_` functions which are now deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future. So you need to start using MySQLi or PDO instead, just as the error notice warned you.

A basic example of using `PDO`:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname) VALUES('Joseph', 'Knoxville')");

$insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Learn more about [php PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

A basic example of using `MySQLi`:

```
$db = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname) VALUES('Joseph', 'Knoxville')");
```

Learn more aboute [php mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Wow, you guys are super awesome Thanks to You Mr Thiago Franca